# Pyramid number sequence using for loop

Tags: java

I need to create this using for loop.

Output

[image: Output]

My code is here:

```
public class Assign01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, i = 0, k;
        for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++) {
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                System.out.print(+i + "\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the ouput.

Output

[image: Output]

Comment: The expected and the actual output look very much the same to me. Please [edit] your question and include the expected and the actual output in readable form.

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track.  First, you should append a space not a tab.  Second, try to add the spaces on the left-hand side (first line 8 spaces, then 6, then 4).  Once you have that, then you're basically done.  Just add another loop like the one you have, but counting down and not up.

Comment: There are so many results online for this kind of things...

Comment: homework or from examination hall ?

Comment: @MunaiDasUdasin I think it's the exam hall.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ... what is the examination hall? I googled for it and found the hits to be inconclusive.

Comment: @hamena314 that means she was literally writing this question here on Stack Overflow so that she would have a valid answer to give in during a test that she was having at the time. Meaning, she posted the test question here, hoping we'd give an answer, and she'd turn it in as if she had written it.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Ah thanks, it sounded to me as if "examination hall" would be a website / book / ... where you could prepare for an upcoming examination. But it's literally going outside into the hall while having a test, posting to SO and waiting for an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I figure it out already.  And this is not an exam hall, its my homework by the way. I'm just having a hard time figuring it out at first. But got it in the end. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Run the for loop in the opposite direction before ascending direction.

```
public class Assign01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, i = 0, k;
        int maxN = 5;
        for (n = 1; n <= maxN; n++) {
            // below prints the tabs to pad the line.
            // this prints a tab (maxN - n) times.
            for(k = n; k < maxN; k++) {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            // below prints the number starting from the biggest, till the lowest
            // I use > 1 instead of >= 1 because you don't want to duplicate 1 twice.
            for (i = n; i > 1; i--) {
                System.out.print(i + "\t");
            }
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                System.out.print(i + "\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output (my local test):

```
                                1
                        2       1       2
                3       2       1       2       3
        4       3       2       1       2       3       4
5       4       3       2       1       2       3       4       5
```

Comment: This was clearly *homework*.  If you're going to give her the answer, you need to *at least* thoroughly explain what it does and why it works.

Comment: OK, added explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What you currently have looks very much like the right hand side of the expected output. So all you need to do is fill in the left side. The left side is just the reverse of the right side so lets see how we can do the reverse of that inner for loop:

```
    for (i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
        System.out.print(+i + "\t");
    }
```

Now if you take that code and add it just above your current inner for loop you'll have something very close to the answer. All you'll need to do is figure out how to remove the duplicated number in the middle and add any required spaces to pad the left and create the pyramid shape.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Assign01 {
    public static final int MIN = 1;
    public static final int MAX = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int j = MIN; j <= MAX; j++) {
            for(int i = MIN, k = MAX; i <= MIN + 2*(MAX-MIN); i++) {
                if(k <= j) {
                    System.out.print("" + k + " ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
                if(i < MAX) {
                    k--;
                } else {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
        1         
      2 1 2       
    3 2 1 2 3     
  4 3 2 1 2 3 4   
5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
```

---

And for example this

```
public static final int MIN = 3;
public static final int MAX = 9;
```

Prints

```
            3             
          4 3 4           
        5 4 3 4 5         
      6 5 4 3 4 5 6       
    7 6 5 4 3 4 5 6 7     
  8 7 6 5 4 3 4 5 6 7 8   
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Considering I've solved the assignment, it's your job to figure out what I did here. That's a more interesting task, no? :)